# Images being pushed down into next line

Tags: html, css

I'm designing an online shop and creating a menu bar from images. It's super simple, and I made the menu the correct width as my page. The only problem is, when I put in all the separate buttons (the menu is divided up into 11 sections), the last image gets pushed down into the next line, even though there is enough space for it to be inline.

Does anyone know how to help?

I should also mention I am a complete beginner to html/css so pretend you're talking to a 10 year old when explaining...

Comment: What you've done so far? Please, post your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: There are many causes: float (generally a PITA) and you haven't counted border size width in the width to inline-block where you've put space between the elements... to get that translated into 10yo speak you're going to have to show code... Saying, "I have a problem, what's the solution?" starts a game of 20 questions (bad since there's only 1 question at a time)

Comment: Add you code snippet